# something fishy in my kernel log - " WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 192" call trace

Tags: boot, kernel, log, i915

This doesn't seem to be a critical issue, but I would like to get some insight on this warning I got this morning when booting my laptop.

I always remove the "quiet" flag from the kernel in grub, which is why I saw the warning message. It makes my laptop hang for about a second only, and then boots normally.
Still I don't like a non-clean boot log =D

```
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891228] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891247] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 192 at /build/linux-BwgxJb/linux-4.4.0/ubuntu/i915/intel_pm.c:3675 skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]()
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891248] WARN_ON(!wm_changed)
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891255] Modules linked in: hid_logitech_hidpp(+) hid_logitech_dj usbhid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops psmouse drm r8169 ahci rtsx_pci mii libahci i2c_hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint video hid pinctrl_intel fjes
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891256] CPU: 0 PID: 192 Comm: kworker/u16:4 Not tainted 4.4.0-43-generic #63-Ubuntu
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891256] Hardware name: GIGABYTE P34V5/P34V5, BIOS FA09 02/17/2016
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891259] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891261]  0000000000000286 0000000047745852 ffff880467847680 ffffffff813f1f93
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891261]  ffff8804678476c8 ffffffffc02a09a0 ffff8804678476b8 ffffffff81081212
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891262]  ffff880035583000 ffff880467e2a148 ffff880035584000 ffff880468a15378
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891262] Call Trace:
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891265]  [<ffffffff813f1f93>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891267]  [<ffffffff81081212>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891268]  [<ffffffff810812ac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891281]  [<ffffffffc01c1fec>] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891293]  [<ffffffffc01c2185>] skl_update_wm+0x185/0x610 [i915_bpo]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891312]  [<ffffffffc02533ef>] ? intel_ddi_enable_transcoder_func+0x17f/0x260 [i915_bpo]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891324]  [<ffffffffc01c5f0e>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915_bpo]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891342]  [<ffffffffc02356c1>] haswell_crtc_enable+0x761/0x8e0 [i915_bpo]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891358]  [<ffffffffc0220cfe>] ? intel_finish_crtc_commit+0xe/0x10 [i915_bpo]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891363]  [<ffffffffc01756d4>] ? drm_atomic_helper_commit_planes_on_crtc+0x154/0x270 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891378]  [<ffffffffc02315c6>] intel_atomic_commit+0x5d6/0x14a0 [i915_bpo]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891388]  [<ffffffffc00dabde>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891396]  [<ffffffffc00db017>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891400]  [<ffffffffc0176e4f>] restore_fbdev_mode+0x22f/0x260 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891407]  [<ffffffffc00d979a>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0x9a/0xb0 [drm]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891411]  [<ffffffffc0179023>] drm_fb_helper_restore_fbdev_mode_unlocked+0x33/0x80 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891414]  [<ffffffffc017909d>] drm_fb_helper_set_par+0x2d/0x50 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891432]  [<ffffffffc024b5fa>] intel_fbdev_set_par+0x1a/0x60 [i915_bpo]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891433]  [<ffffffff8146e340>] fbcon_init+0x570/0x5f0
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891435]  [<ffffffff81500356>] visual_init+0xd6/0x130
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891436]  [<ffffffff81502271>] do_bind_con_driver+0x1c1/0x3a0
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891437]  [<ffffffff81502789>] do_take_over_console+0x149/0x1b0
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891438]  [<ffffffff8146a1a7>] do_fbcon_takeover+0x57/0xb0
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891439]  [<ffffffff8146edb8>] fbcon_event_notify+0x658/0x750
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891440]  [<ffffffff810a180a>] notifier_call_chain+0x4a/0x70
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891441]  [<ffffffff810a1b47>] __blocking_notifier_call_chain+0x47/0x60
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891442]  [<ffffffff810a1b76>] blocking_notifier_call_chain+0x16/0x20
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891443]  [<ffffffff81474a4b>] fb_notifier_call_chain+0x1b/0x20
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891444]  [<ffffffff81476bbf>] register_framebuffer+0x20f/0x350
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891448]  [<ffffffffc017934a>] drm_fb_helper_initial_config+0x28a/0x420 [drm_kms_helper]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891463]  [<ffffffffc024c1af>] intel_fbdev_initial_config+0x1f/0x30 [i915_bpo]
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891464]  [<ffffffff810a3328>] async_run_entry_fn+0x48/0x150
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891465]  [<ffffffff8109a3e5>] process_one_work+0x165/0x480
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891466]  [<ffffffff8109a74b>] worker_thread+0x4b/0x4c0
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891467]  [<ffffffff8109a700>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891468]  [<ffffffff810a0928>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891469]  [<ffffffff810a0850>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891471]  [<ffffffff81831c4f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891471]  [<ffffffff810a0850>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
Oct 18 11:38:06 cerberus kernel: [    2.891472] ---[ end trace fa29fd9c77a8df51 ]---
```

Any idea what could trigger this message?

Thanks in advance!